# Multiple join with groupby in linq

Tags: c#, linq

i have 5 table from which i want to get some information using linq.i am using following query for reading data from data .

```
var query = (from GRD in _tblStudents.GetQueryable() 
             join apt in _tblApplicants.GetQueryable() 
                  on GRD.ApplicantID equals apt.ApplicantID
             join cls in _tblClasses.GetQueryable() 
                  on GRD.CityID equals cls.ClassID
             join prg in _tblPrograms.GetQueryable() 
                  on cls.ProgramID equals prg.ProgramID
             join city in _tblCities.GetQueryable() 
                  on GRD.CityID equals city.CityID
             where GRD.AcademicYearID == yearId && cls.ProgramID == programId
             group apt by new{apt.Gender} into grouped
             select new CityWiseStudentModel
             {
                  CityName=city.CityName, 
                  //'city' does not exist in the current context
                  Gender = grouped.Count(),
                  programName=prg.Program, 
                 //'prg' does not exist in the current context
              }   

           );
```

How i can get City name from **city** table and program name from **prg** table

Comment: Try `join into` instead of just `join` to propagate the grouped items throughout the whole query. Note that you will need to rewrite the query since you cannot have a `join` directly following a `join into` (need of an intermediate `select`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`group <--> by <--> into <-->` is changed your scope to `IGrouping<a,b>`

My opinion is not only `apt.Gender` is your key but `city.CityName` and `prg.Program`

try this (or some similar):

```
group apt by new{apt.Gender, city, prg} into grouped
select new CityWiseStudentModel
{
     CityName = grouped.Key.city.CityName, 
     Gender = grouped.Count(), //rename GenderCount
     programName = grouped.Key.prg.Program,
     // Gender = grouped.Key.Gender,
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remember that `grouped` will **only hold the things you've grouped.** If you only group `adt`, then `city` and `prg` will not be available in your select.

So you'll need to:

1. Include **city** and **program** into `grouped` (otherwise they're not available)
2. Access `CityName` and `Program` inside the `grouped` **collection**

Something like this should do the trick:

```
...
group new { apt, cls, prg, city } by new{apt.Gender} into grouped
select new CityWiseStudentModel
{
   CityNames = grouped.Select(g => g.city.CityName),  
   ...
   programNames = grouped.Select(g => g.prg.Program)
}
```

Comment: I think the `= ap` is misplaced.